# how to allow outgoing traffic with firewalld / libvirt on CentOS 8?

Tags: centos, firewall, redhat, libvirt, firewalld

I installed a CentOS 8 guest on a CentOS 8 host using libvirt. However firewalld is blocking all outgoing traffic from the guest to the internet unless I use `target=ACCEPT` for the libvirt zone.

The datacenter provides two separate IPv4 addresses for the server and I want to use one of these IP addresses for the guest VM.

```
# virsh net-dumpxml public
<network connections='1'>
  <name>public</name>
  <uuid>…</uuid>
  <forward mode='route'/>
  <bridge name='br-public' zone='libvirt-public' stp='on' delay='0'/>
  <mac address='…'/>
  <ip address='(HOST IP)' netmask='255.255.255.255' />
  <ip family='ipv6' address='…' prefix='128' />
</network>

# firewall-cmd --list-all --zone=libvirt-public
libvirt-public (active)
  target: %%REJECT%%
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces: br-public
  sources: 
  services: dhcp dhcpv6 dns ssh
  ports: 
  protocols: icmp ipv6-icmp
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports: 
  source-ports: 
  icmp-blocks: 
  rich rules:
```

I assumed that ICMP, SSH, and DNS should work fine as these are listed in the firewalld zone.

However somehow firewalld on the host blocks all outgoing traffic:

```
(guest) # ping 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
From (HOST IP) icmp_seq=1 Packet filtered
```

When I log all denied packages on the host I can see that firewalld is rejecting these network conenctions:

```
"filter_FWDI_libvirt-public_REJECT: "IN=br-public OUT=enp3s0 MAC=… SRC=(GUEST IP) DST=8.8.8.8 LEN=84 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=63 ID=40405 DF PROTO=ICMP TYPE=8 CODE=0 ID=1594 SEQ=3
```

Everything starts to work as expected when I set the zone target to `ACCEPT` (though I'd prefer to use REJECT):

```
# firewall-cmd --zone=libvirt-public --permanent --set-target=ACCEPT
# firewall-cmd --reload
```

So obviously I don't understand firewalld's zone configuration. Do `services`/`protocols` only refer to *incoming* connections? How to allow certain *outgoing* connections (but not all)?